How to fix Package 'gtk4' requires 'gio-2.0 >= 2.76.0' but version of gio-2.0 is 2.74.4
Trying to compile a c program that uses the GTK library and getting the following error:
Package 'gtk4' requires 'gio-2.0 >= 2.76.0' but version of gio-2.0 is 2.74.4

gtk4 (and all other versions of gtk on this system) are installed via Homebrew. I've inquired with the Homebrew team and they have no answers other than to ensure my version of gtk4 is up to date, and it is.
environment:
-- macOS (same error on both Intel (big sur) and Apple Silicon (Sonoma))
-- gtk4: 4.14.4
-- glib: 2.80.2
How can I fix this?

Anyone able to assist here?

This was resolved: Was using GStreamer to loop in GTK code. GStreamer was installed both via Homebrew and as Apple .pkg.
Removing the Homebrew version of GStreamer helped resolve. Ensuring Homebrew versions of GTK+3 and GTK4 were updated probably didn't hurt either.
Ensured PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH are pointing the correct distros (Homebrew and Apple Frameworks).
